# Can I have a Adsense fallback on Google Ad Manager only if a variable is set or something?

Tags: adsense, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

On my site, I serve ads to both visitors/free members and paid accounts. The ads are served with Google Ad Manager.

In the case of visitors/free members, I would like to fall back on Adsense if there is no Ad Manager ad to display.

In the case of paid accounts, I would like to fall back to a house ad.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

1. if user is loggued, add a key member=true to your GPT page level targetings.
2. then target your adsense line items to the inventory with key member=true only

To define page level key/values :

`googletag.pubads().setTargeting('member', 'true');`

Just keep in mind setTargeting only accepts strings or array values as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_setTargeting) (bolean or integer won't work)

[Here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7438540?hl=en) is how to set your Adsense campaign up in Google Ad Manager.